# Codeigniter Arithmetic inside of set statement

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to update a field in my table with values from `array key`, below is statement but I cannot get to work when using array key. I am new and likely not creating the statement correctly. Any help is appreciated.

```
$this->db->set('product_qoh', 'product_qoh - $item['sold']' ,FALSE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below worked for me, the above was replacing the cell value with the negate of $item['sold'].

```
$this->db->set('product_qoh', 'product_qoh - '  .$item['sold'] ,FALSE);
```